# How to get access token to GCP Identity-Aware-Proxy from iOS(Swift)

Tags: swift, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, access-token

I want to get the access token to access Identity-Aware-Proxy of GCP from iOS(Swift).

I just add [google-auth-library-swift](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-swift) pod and tried using **ServiceAccountTokenProvider**, and got the likely accessToken. But even when I add it to the header with Bearer keyword, I couldn't access IAP protected API.

I doubt the format of access token because when I tried with Java with this [sample code](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#iap_make_request-java) , the token format is different from the one I got with swift library.

Do you know how to get access token to get access to IAP protected API?

```
let scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/iam"]
guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: Constants.GAE.serviceAccountCredentialJSON, withExtension: nil) else {
    fatalError("Failed To read JSON")
}
guard let provider = ServiceAccountTokenProvider(credentialsURL: url, scopes: scopes) else {
    fatalError("Failed To create ServiceAccountTokenProvider")
}

do {
    try provider.withToken { [weak self] (token, error) in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        if let token = token, let accessToken = token.AccessToken {
            logger.debug("GAE TOKEN with token \(accessToken)")
            return
        } else {
            if let error = error {
                print("GAE TOKEN with error \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            } else {
                let error = IdentityAwareProxyError.failedToGetAccessToken
                print("GAE TOKEN with error \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
        }
    }
} catch let error {
    print("GAE TOKEN error \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Comment: You need an Identity Token, not an Access Token to authorize requests in the HTTP Authorization header.

Comment: Thanks. But google-auth-library doesn't have other token format. 
After a half day struggle, I finally self-solved the problem.

I separated google-auth-library classes and changed JWTClaimSet parameters. I've done with iss, aud, iat, exp, target_audience and add kid to JWTHeader. After that, the generated JWT token changed. And I could access IAP protected GAE API.
I don't think this is the best answer because I don't have enough knowledge of OAuth2 but I could...

Comment: Yes it does: https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs Look for Fetching ID Tokens.